# How to wait on multiple multiprocess.Process to finish execution when they exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-multiprocessing

I need to wait for multiple processes to finish execution. I am using multiprocess.Process, because I want to adjust oom score of the subprocesses before executing them. After research, I wanted to use multiprocessing.connection.wait and sentinel values of subprocesses to wait on them.

Consider the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.connection
import os
from datetime import datetime

def adj_oom_score_exec(*command: str):
    with open("/proc/{}/oom_score_adj".format(os.getpid()), "w") as f:
        f.write("500")
    os.execv(command[0], command)
    exit(198)

pp = multiprocessing.Process(target=adj_oom_score_exec, args=["/usr/bin/sleep", "1"])
pp.start()
print(datetime.now())
multiprocessing.connection.wait([pp.sentinel])
print(datetime.now())
```

The code outputs two timestamps with difference in milliseconds. `multiprocessing.connection.wait()` does **not** wait for the command to finish execution. How to make it wait? Note that `pp.join()` does work and because subprocess is not a daemon, Python will actually wait for the process to finish.

Comment: Couldn't you also do this with `subprocess.Popen` using `preexec_fn` for the adjustment?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Och, thanks so much, I did not know that existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic. I was under the impression that `multiprocess.Process.sentinel` is a `pidfd_open` returned file descriptor. I suspect that `multiprocessing.Process` opens a `pipe()` and `sentinel` is just a normal pipe. Because python closes the pipe when `os.execv`, `select()` on it just returns immediately. Moreover, today I learned that `subprocess.Popen.wait()` (called by `multiprocessing.Process.join()`) that is just a busy loop that calls `waitpid` every 500us.

Instead, use `subprocess.Popen` with `preexec_fn` to set the oom_score_adj. In the main thread do `threading.Event.wait()` and in SIGCHLD signal handler set the event to notify main thread to handle one of the childs.